# How do I run multiple commands in SSH through Java?

Tags: java, ssh

***How do I run multiple commands in SSH using Java runtime?***

**the command:** ssh user@127.0.0.1 'export MYVAR=this/dir/is/cool; /run/my/script
/myscript; echo $MYVAR'

```
@Test
  public void testSSHcmd() throws Exception
  {
    StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder();

    cmd.append("ssh ");
    cmd.append("user@127.0.0.1 ");
    cmd.append("'export ");
    cmd.append("MYVAR=this/dir/is/cool; ");
    cmd.append("/run/my/script/myScript; ");
    cmd.append("echo $MYVAR'");

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd.toString());
  }
```

**The command by its self will work but when trying to execute from java run-time it does not. Any suggestions or advice?**

Comment: What doesn't work? What happens?

Comment: I love stackoverflow. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the newer [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class instead of `Runtime.exec`. You can construct one by specifying the program and its list of arguments as shown in my code below. You don't need to use single-quotes around the command. You should also read the stdout and stderr streams and `waitFor` for the process to finish.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ssh", 
                                       "user@127.0.0.1", 
                                       "export MYVAR=this/dir/is/cool; /run/my/script/myScript; echo $MYVAR");
pb.redirectErrorStream(); //redirect stderr to stdout
Process process = pb.start();
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Hi dogbane I need to run multiple ssh commands in a single run, the link which you shared was not clear to me. So ple if you have any clear document can you please share to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The veriant of `Runtime.exec` you are calling splits the command string into several tokens which are then passed to ssh. What you need is one of the variants where you can provide a string array. Put the complete remote part into one argument while stripping the outer quotes. Example

```
Runtime.exec(new String[]{ 
    "ssh", 
    "user@127.0.0.1", 
    "export MYVAR=this/dir/is/cool; /run/my/script/myScript; echo $MYVAR"
});
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

If the `Process` just hangs I suspect that `/run/my/script/myScript` outputs something to `stderr`. You need to handle that output aswell as `stdout`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String[] cmd = {"ssh", "root@localhost", "'ls asd; ls'" };
    final Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

    // ignore all errors (print to std err)
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
                String in;
                while((in = err.readLine()) != null)
                    System.err.println(in);
                err.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }.start();

    // handle std out
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    char[] data = new char[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = reader.read(data)) != -1)
        ret.append(data, 0, read);
    reader.close();

    // wait for the exit code
    int exitCode = p.waitFor();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) library. It allows you to do all sorts of SSH things with remote hosts including executing commands and scripts.

They have examples listed here: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right way to do it:

```
Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start <full path>");
```

For example:

```
Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
rt.exec("cmd.exe /c start C:/aa.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SSHJ from https://github.com/shikhar/sshj/

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final SSHClient ssh = new SSHClient();
    ssh.loadKnownHosts();

    ssh.connect("10.x.x.x");
    try {
        //ssh.authPublickey(System.getProperty("root"));
        ssh.authPassword("user", "xxxx");
        final Session session = ssh.startSession();

        try {
            final Command cmd = session.exec("cd /backup; ls; ./backup.sh");
            System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());
            cmd.join(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("\n** exit status: " + cmd.getExitStatus());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    } finally {
        ssh.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Depicus I need to run multiple ssh commands in a single run, the link which you shared was not clear to me. So ple if you have any clear document can you please share to me. Thanks

Comment: Hi Anand, basically separate each command with a ; and you should be good to go. The link works for me.

Comment: okay Depicus. I need to run multiple ssh commands with select query to view the status. I can't execute the query if you know how to execute select query please let me know. Here I Show the full commands. cd /aep/cu/scripts/;./dbutil.ksh E1QA;select * from tgpoa01.aud_trail_dtl where AUD_TRAIL_REC_ID = '-9223372036798689753'

Comment: The `System.out.println(IOUtils.readFully(cmd.getInputStream()).toString());` line should return any output