# java: using ssh command tom make multi-line comments on gerrit

Tags: java, ssh, multiline, gerrit

when I am using shell to publish a comment on gerrit, for example,

ssh -p 29418 gerritlink gerrit review --verified=0 '--message=[FAILURE] COMMIT MESSAGE CHECK FAIL.

PCPID not exist.

A360-ID not exist.' d9a5d29799ada8237679efd1121cd7e3a85f333d

**and this works fine in gerrit comments, you can see multi-line there.**
***but when I use java to call the command, all the sentences are in one line.
how can I make the comments in multiline in java?***

Comment: Is gerrit your library for communicating with your repository ? A very quick google search says it's a web-based code management tool though. Please show us some code to be able to help you here.

Comment: gerrit_message = "[FAILURE] COMMIT MESSAGE CHECK FAIL." + "\r\n\r\n" + message_PCP  + "\r\n\r\n" + message_A360;
runCmd("ssh -p 29418 gerrit.com gerrit review --verified=0 '--message=" + gerrit_message  + "\' " + strGERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION, listener, workspace);
and when I run this command in shell, it works for multiline; and all the sentences are in one line after the java run.

Comment: BTW, runCmd is just a method for call the shell command, too long to paste here

Comment: Try semicolons (i.e ';' or '&&' without quotes) between different commands.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure if this will help but you can try separating your commands using `;` or `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

---

Here are two solutions that worked for me:

1. Gerrit collapses single newlines, so use double newlines "\n\n"
   instead of "\r\n".
2. Prefix each line with spaces and that will convince Gerrit to show them as separate mono-spaced lines. The paragraph gets formatted using HTML pre style which is useful for code samples.

Sources: [Re: Multiline comments in gerrit](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.repo/5321) and [Comment
    formatting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/S58dBK1nQBw)

I also had to run the ssh command using ProcessBuilder to get the above solutions to work.

E.g. Sending message using Solution #1:

```
String solution1_msg = "Test1\n\nThis is a test\n\nTesting has completed"
String solution2_msg = "Test2\n   This is a test\n   Testing has completed"

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ssh", "-p", "29418", "<gerrit server>",
    "gerrit", "review", "--message=\"" + solution1_message + "\"commit SHA-1>");
pb.redirectErrorStream(); //redirect stderr to stdout
Process process = pb.start();
InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
process.waitFor();
```

Same code works for Solution #2 as well; pass `solution2_message` as the message instead of `solution1_message`.

Source: [How do I run multiple commands in SSH through Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7611715)

Answer (score 0):

I will explain it in shell. The problem is related to the quotes that are been used incorrectly.

```
$> msg="- line1                               
- line2
- line3
- line4"
$> echo ${msg}
$> - line1 - line2 - line3 - line4
$> echo "${msg}"
- line1
- line2
- line3
- line4
```

The same thing with Gerrit command, you to have to insure that needed quotes are in the needed place.

```
ssh -p 29418 admin@localhost gerrit review 3,2 --project test -m "'"${msg}"'" --code-review 1
```

Administrator
Patch Set 2:

- hello - wordl - line3 - line4

```
ssh -p 29418 admin@localhost gerrit review 3,2 --project test -m "'""${msg}""'" --code-review 1
```

Administrator
Patch Set 2:

- line1
- line2
- line3
- line4